# error of reading Json string in C# by JsonConvert

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio

I need to read data from a Json string in C#.

The Json string is like:

```
{ 
 "data_level":{

   "performance":{
    "@value":"1000",
    "@size":"10",
  },
  "points":{
    "@type":"profit",
    "tier":{
        "@below":"80",
        "@above":"100"
    },
    "kids":[
        {
            "@kid":"150"
        },
        {
            "@kid":"200"
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

My C# code:

```
 var my_dic = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(json_string);
 var my_data = my_dic["data_level"]
 string v = my_data["performance"]["@size"];
```

For "kids", I have two child "kid" have the same name but differne value. How to get all of them instead of only the one last read ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Json looks invalid...

Comment: I missed a "{". For whoever voted down, just due to the typo ?

Comment: I didn't downvoted... The reply bellow is correct... You tried to get the first child of a property with no children...

Comment: Thanks, I have updated OP. But, I got a new problem.

Comment: You should use a foreach, or some lib to fill an array with the data...

Answer (score 2):

You should leave out the last `[0]` .

Answer (score 0):

For the updated question:

```
my_children = my_dic["points"]["kids"];
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> pair in my_children)
{
    Console.WriteLine(pair.Key, pair.Value["@kid"]);
}
```

This should work...

Comment: Please avoid to edit the question multiple times... Zotta had the correct reply to the original question... If you made a mistake, simply drop the question... The updated question seems more legitimate, so you may keep it...